# Hyperlink inside html table cell becomes non clickable after window maximization

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap.I have hyperlinks inside a HTML table's cells one of them also trigger  a bootstrap Modal class and another does hyperlinks to itself.They works fine when the browser window is kept small in size ,but the hyperlinks stops working as soon the browser window is maximized.Even the courser doesn't changes on pointing to the links.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="assets/img/apple-icon.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

 <title>Payroll</title>

 <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS     -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Animation library for notifications   -->
    <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!--  Paper Dashboard core CSS    -->
    <link href="assets/css/paper-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/debt2.css">

    <!--  CSS for Demo Purpose, don't include it in your project     -->
    <link href="assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!--  Fonts and icons     -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="assets/css/themify-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-background-color="white" data-active-color="success">

    <!--
  Tip 1: you can change the color of the sidebar's background using: data-background-color="white | black"
  Tip 2: you can change the color of the active button using the data-active-color="primary | info | success | warning | danger"
 -->

     <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com" class="simple-text">
                    Creative Tim
                </a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li >
                    <a href="dashboard.html">
                        <i class="ti-panel"></i>
                        <p>Dashboard</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a  href="user.html">
                        <i class="ti-user"></i>
                        <p>Human Resources</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="table.html">
                        <i class="ti-view-list-alt"></i>
                        <p>Table List</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="typography.html">
                        <i class="ti-truck"></i>
                        <p>Trucking</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="icons.html">
                        <i class="ti-pencil-alt2"></i>
                        <p>Icons</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="maps.html">
                        <i class="ti-map"></i>
                        <p>Accounts</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="notifications.html">
                        <i class="ti-bell"></i>
                        <p>Notifications</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
   
            </ul>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-panel">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar bar1"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar bar2"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar bar3"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="ti-panel"></i>
        <p>Stats</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <i class="ti-bell"></i>
                                    <p class="notification">5</p>
         <p>Notifications</p>
         <b class="caret"></b>
                              </a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another notification</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
      <li>
                            <a href="#">
        <i class="ti-settings"></i>
        <p>Settings</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <div class="content">
            <div class="card">
            
   
<div cls="containerer">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3">
        <ul id="ul1">
            <li><strong>Mid Level</strong></li>
            <li><strong>Top Level</strong></li>
            <li><strong>Low Level</strong></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    
  </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8" >
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="button" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><strong>Add New</strong></a>
        </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4" style="background-color:lavender;"><strong>Add New--></strong></div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
  
           <div id="custom-search-input">
                            <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                                <input type="text" class="search-query form-control" id="input1" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search th names............" />
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                                        <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
 </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="button" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"><i class="ti-money"></i></a>
<div class="col-md-12">
<table id="myTable">
<tr class="header">
    <th>Name</th>
   <!-- <th>Month</th>-->
    <th>Advance Paid</th>
    <th>Salary Amount</th>
    <th>Final Salary Recievable(₹)</th>
    <th>Pay</th>
    <th>Exit</th>
    
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Akash Saha</td>
    <td>₹500</td>
    <td>₹17000</td>
    <td>₹16500</td>
      <td><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" style="display:block;"><i class="ti-money"></i></a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="ti-close"></i></a></td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Diesh Pandey</td>
    <td>₹10000</td>
      <td>₹0</td>
    <td>₹10000</td>
      <td>n/a</td>
  </tr>

</table>

    </div>
    
 
     
   
    
  
    </div>
        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <nav class="pull-left">
                    <ul>

                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com">
                                Creative Tim
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://blog.creative-tim.com">
                               Blog
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com/license">
                                Licenses
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="copyright pull-right">
                    &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>, made with <i class="fa fa-heart heart"></i> by <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com">Creative Tim</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
</div>




    <!--   Core JS Files   -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <!--  Checkbox, Radio & Switch Plugins -->
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-checkbox-radio.js"></script>

 <!--  Charts Plugin -->
 <script src="assets/js/chartist.min.js"></script>

    <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>

    <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <!-- Paper Dashboard Core javascript and methods for Demo purpose -->
 <script src="assets/js/paper-dashboard.js"></script>

 <!-- Paper Dashboard DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
 <script src="assets/js/demo.js"></script>
    <!-- Modal -->
 
    </div>
   
    </div>
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Info</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="modal-a">  
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Employee Details</label>
              <input type="text" id="empdetails"class="form-control" placeholder="Employee's Name with Address in short"><br>
              <label>Select Level</label><br>
                  <select style="width:100%;" id="level">
                  <option value="top level">Top</option>
                  <option value="mid level">Mid</option>
                  <option value="low level">Low</option>
                  </select><br>
                  <label>Position Details</label>
                  <input type="text"  id="posdetails" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter position Details"><br>
                  <label>Enter Starting Date</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start" placeholder="Enter Start Date" value="N/A"><br>
                  <label>Salary Amount in Rs(₹)</label>
                  <input type="text" id="salaryamt" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the salary amount"><br>
                  <label>Balence Amount in Rs(₹)</label>
                  <input type="text" id="bal" value="0" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Balance amount">
         
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-success">Enter</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
           
    </div>
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Make Payment</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="modal-a">  
              <div class="form-group">
            
                  <label>Payment Amount in Rs(₹)</label>
                  <input type="text" id="bal" value="0" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Balance amount">
         
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-success">Enter</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
           
    </div>
    </body>

  


 <script type="text/javascript">
     function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("input1");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
//variable declerations
        var empdetails,level,posdetails,start,salaryamt,bal;
        empdetails=$("#empdetails").val();
        level=$().val"#level selected"().val();
        posdetails=$("#posdetails").val();
        start=$("#start").val();
        salaryamt=$("#salaryamt").val();
        bal=$("#bal").val();
//database starts here
 details={"Employee Details":empdetails,"level":level,"posdetails":posdetails,"Start":start,"bal":bal};
users.insert(details,function(err, doc){
        console.log('Inserted', doc.empdetails, 'with ID', doc._id);        
});

 </script>

</html>
```

Comment: You should provide an example. We could not help you without any kind of sourcecode.

Comment: Sounds like the link in the modal are dynamically generated...

Comment: not dynamically generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your other elements is essentially "overlapping" your link when you are maximized.

Do a right click and "inspect" the link when your window is maximized and it will highlight the element that is overlapping your link.

You will most likely need to solve this with z-index and position: relative